# print 0 to 10 in Ascending Order in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have tried following Code but it did not work. What is the Error in this Code..?

```
asc(0):-
    write(0).
asc(X):-
    asc(X-1),
    write(X).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog doesn't have arithmetic expressions that automatically evaluate to values like in other languages. `X-1` does not denote an arithmetic value; it is just a term.

```
?- X = 5, Y = X - 1.
X = 5,
Y = 5-1.
```

To compute an arithmetic value, you must use the `is/2` predicate:

```
?- X = 5, Y is X - 1.
X = 5,
Y = 4.
```

So instead of calling `asc(X-1)` you must compute the value of `X - 1` separately and pass that result to the recursive call:

```
asc(0) :-
    write(0).
asc(X) :-
    X > 0,
    X1 is X - 1,
    asc(X1),
    write(X).
```

The guard `X > 0` is needed to avoid infinite recursion along the negative numbers.